# Array with Strings that are displayed on new line with indentation

Tags: macros, indentation

I would like to have something like this in LaTex:

[image: indented text]

Is there a function that does that? Otherwise I would like to have a command that I can pass an array of strings, separated by a comma/semicolon, which then generates the above output; e.g. `\createindentedtext(string1, string2, string3)`.

Output:

```
string1
    string2
        string3
```

Is that even possible?

Using egreg's solution almost works.
The code I used is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{8pt}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\createindentedlist}{m}
{
    \group_begin:
    \skip_zero:N \parskip
    \skip_set:Nn \parindent { 1.5em }
    \par\medskip
    \cil_iterate:n { #1 }
    \medskip
    \group_end:
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cil_iterate:n #1
 {
  \int_set:Nn \cil_iteration_int { 0 } % 0 = first line gets indented; -1 = skip first line
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \hspace*{\cil_iteration_int \parindent} \textsf{##1}
    \int_incr:N \cil_iteration_int
    \par\nobreak
   }
 }
\int_new:N \cil_iteration_int
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section*{Section}
\createindentedlist{string1,string2,string3}
\end{document}
```

The indentation is a little off, no matter if I ignore the first string or not (0 or -1).

[image: wrong indentation]

Is it further possible to insert a symbol for all strings, except the first one? So it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Please, try making that code into a compilable example (with your setting of parskip and parindent).

Comment: The first paragraph of a section has a special treatment with respect to indentation. Do you *really* need the command at the start of a section?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I ONLY need it at the start of a section. As mentioned I want to achieve a JavaDoc look&feel: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\createindentedlist}{m}
 {
  \par\medskip
  \cil_iterate:n { #1 }
  \medskip
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cil_iterate:n #1
 {
  \int_set:Nn \cil_iteration_int { -1 }
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \hspace*{\cil_iteration_int \parindent} \textsf{##1}
    \int_incr:N \cil_iteration_int
    \par\nobreak
   }
 }
\int_new:N \cil_iteration_int
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\createindentedlist{string1,string2,string3}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The first item will not be indented; change `-1` to `0` if you prefer to indent it. I've added `\textsf` around the entry to be typeset to show were acting for setting the format.

---

[image]

---

In case you're using the `parskip` package (or set manually the `\parskip` and use a zero `\parindent`) change the first definition into

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\createindentedlist}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \skip_zero:N \parskip
  \skip_set:Nn \parindent { 1.5em }
  \par\medskip
  \cil_iterate:n { #1 }
  \medskip
  \group_end:
 }
```

---

Using this command at the start of a section is different, because the first paragraph is treated somewhat specially: you can try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\createindentedlist}{m}
 {
  \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \skip_zero:N \parskip
    \skip_set:Nn \parindent { 1.5em }
    \cil_iterate:n { #1 }
    \medskip
  }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cil_iterate:n #1
 {
  \int_set:Nn \cil_iteration_int { -1 }
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \hspace*{\cil_iteration_int \parindent} \textsf{##1}
    \int_incr:N \cil_iteration_int
    \par\nobreak
   }
 }
\int_new:N \cil_iteration_int
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}    
\createindentedlist{string1,string2,string3}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what the dependencies are? It works fine as a standalone document, but when I copy it to my working project it just displays the three strings below each other without identation.

Comment: @cherrung You probably are setting the parindent to zero, which is something I can't recommend. I've added a workaround.

Comment: Yes, you were right. Agh. I changed the indentation to zero, because I didn't like the way paragraphs looked. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @cherrung I've added the workaround. But, frankly, the indentation has been in use for five centuries (in movable type printing) and it's hard to believe that people did badly for such a long time. :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I like the new command code :) However I get the following error now: ! Undefined control sequence.
\createindentedlist #1-> \group 
                                _begin: \skip _zero:N \parskip \skip _set:Nn...
l.5 \createindentedlist{string1,string2,string3}

Comment: @cherrung You still need to place the code between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`.

Comment: @cherrung The code should replace the similar one in the code given initially.

Comment: @egreg Thanks again. It almost works now. Indentation for first string is little off though. Can you please look at my first post again. I edited it using your code.

Comment: @egreg You are just amazing! The last version worked perfectly!

Comment: @egreg Ok, I was just wondering how I would add a little more vertical space for the upcoming text after the last indented list item? What can I add inside the newdocumentcommand bracket?

Comment: @cherrung That's controlled by the `\medskip`; you can try with `\bigskip` or with `\vspace{...}` where you can set any space you want.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `pgf`'s `\foreach` macro to iterate over the list and increase the horizontal indent at each iteration, and use `tikz` to add the lines.

To make it easier to control the formatting for each of the list members,
I have defined three different commands for the first, middle, and last list members:

```
\newcommand*{\FormatFirstListMember}[1]{\textcolor{magenta}{\texttt{#1}}}%
\newcommand*{\FormatMiddleListMember}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\texttt{#1}}}%
\newcommand*{\FormatLastListMember}[1]{\texttt{#1}}%
```

With the above settings, here are the result of using:

```
\createindentedtext{java.lang.Object, java.awt.Component3, java.awt.Container, javax.swing.JComponent}

\createindentedtext[50pt]{java.lang.Object, java.awt.Component3, java.awt.Container, javax.swing.JComponent}
```

[image]

### Notes:

- The optional first parameter to `\createindentedtext` can be used to override the default setting of the indent amount. Default value is the value specified in `\DefaultIndentSize`.
- The `\FormatFirstListMember`, `\FormatMiddleListMember`, `\FormatLastListMember` can be modified to tweak the desired formatting to be applied to the list members.
- You can adjust the settings in `\ConnectIndentedText` to tweak the formatting of the lines.
- The current setting of the vertical bar joining the elements is set to half the indent size. This can be tweaked as desired by changing the `0.5` constant in the definition of `\ConnectIndentedText`.  It can also be adjusted to always be under a specific letter (such as `v` in `java`) by replacing `-0.5*#1` in this macro with an appropriate expression using `\widthof{}` from the [the `calc` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc) (which is different than what `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` loads).
- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe) was used to show the position of the text relative to the margins.  The `\noindent` ensures that your text is shifted relative to the margin.
- This requires two runs. Once to determine the end point of the lines, and the second to draw them.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\newlength{\DefaultIndentSize}%
\setlength{\DefaultIndentSize}{25pt}% adjust to suit

% Specify the formatting of each of the list members
\newcommand*{\FormatFirstListMember}[1]{\textcolor{magenta}{\texttt{#1}}}%
\newcommand*{\FormatMiddleListMember}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\texttt{#1}}}%
\newcommand*{\FormatLastListMember}[1]{\texttt{#1}}%


\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\newcommand*{\ConnectIndentedText}[2][\DefaultIndentSize]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \draw [thick, blue]
            ($(#2)+(0,0.5ex)$) --
            ($(#2)+(-0.5*#1,0.5ex)$) --
            ($(#2)+(-0.5*#1,2.0ex)$) 
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
}%

\newcounter{TotalNumberOfListMembers}%
\newcommand{\SetTotalNumberOfListMembers}[1]{%
    \setcounter{TotalNumberOfListMembers}{0}%
    \foreach \member in {#1} {%
        \stepcounter{TotalNumberOfListMembers}%
    }%
}%


\newlength{\IndentLength}%
\newcounter{CurrentListMemberCount}%
\newtoggle{FirstIndentedText}%
\newcommand*{\createindentedtext}[2][\DefaultIndentSize]{%
    \setlength{\IndentLength}{0pt}%
    \SetTotalNumberOfListMembers{#2}%
    \setcounter{CurrentListMemberCount}{0}%
    \global\toggletrue{FirstIndentedText}%
    \foreach \member in {#2} {%
        \stepcounter{CurrentListMemberCount}%
        \par\noindent\hspace*{\IndentLength}%
        \tikzmark{start}%
        \iftoggle{FirstIndentedText}{%
            \FormatFirstListMember{\member}%
        }{%
            \IfEq{\the\value{CurrentListMemberCount}}{\the\value{TotalNumberOfListMembers}}{%
                \FormatLastListMember{\member}%
            }{%
                \FormatMiddleListMember{\member}%
            }%
            \ConnectIndentedText[#1]{start}%
        }%
        \global\addtolength{\IndentLength}{#1}%
        \global\togglefalse{FirstIndentedText}%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
    \createindentedtext{java.lang.Object, java.awt.Component3,  java.awt.Container, javax.swing.JComponent}

    \bigskip
    \createindentedtext[50pt]{java.lang.Object, java.awt.Component3, java.awt.Container, javax.swing.JComponent}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

A possible solution would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newlength\CurrIndent
\newcommand\IndentedList[1]{\setlength\CurrIndent{0cm}\par\noindent%
  \expandafter\Indented@List#1,,\@nil}
\def\Indented@List#1,#2,#3\@nil{%
  \hspace*{\CurrIndent}\texttt{#1}%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\par\else\newline
    \addtolength\CurrIndent{1cm}\Indented@List#2,#3\@nil\fi}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\IndentedList{string1,string2,string3}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]