# Process Last Item in \ForEach (forarray package)

Tags: formatting, counters, loops, foreach

The following command of the **forarray** package

```
\ForEach{,}{\thislevelitem(\the\thislevelcount) : }}{x,y,z}
```

produces the output

```
x(1) : y(2) : z(3) :
```

I want to have the same output without the last ":".

The **forarray** package does not provide any command like `\maxount` to test if `\thislevelcount == \maxcount`. Surly I could test for the first item `\thislevelcount == 0` but what to do if this cannot be done for some reason?

How can I process the last item separately if the number of items is variable/unknown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cheat and prepend `:` to all the items except for the first

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forarray}
\begin{document}
  \ForEach{,}{\ifnum\thislevelcount=1\else : \fi\thislevelitem(\the\thislevelcount)}{x,y,z}
\end{document}
```

or you can use the totcount package to get the number of items in the array

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forarray}
\usepackage{totcount}
\begin{document}
  \newtotcounter{myarray}
  \ForEach{,}{\stepcounter{myarray}\thislevelitem(\the\thislevelcount)\ifnum\thislevelcount=\totvalue{myarray}\else : \fi}{x,y,z}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: The first is okay but it’s not the last item. However, I used the first item solution (as mentioned in my question). I do not understand the second solution. How does the totcount package know the number of total items in your example?

Comment: @Ronny knowing the total number of items is the magic of the `totcount` package. Basically the package requires two passes. On the first pass it writes the final value of the counter to the aux file and on the second pass it reads the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `\indrisloop` macro of the **catoptions** package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\begin{document}
\def\do#1{%
  #1(\indrisnr)\space\iflastindris\else:\space\fi
}
\indrisloop{x,y,x}\do
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Similar to my comments in [pgffor: Special treatment for last item in \foreach-list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59808/4301) the other answers here provide solutions to accomplish the task at hand, but don't address the problem in the title of the question.

One way to detect the last list member and treat it differently is to count the number of members at the start of the list processing and compare that to `\the\thislevelcount` to know when we have come to the last one:

[image]

### Notes:

- I am using [the `xstring` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/) for the numerical comparison as I prefer it's syntax, but this could easily be adapted to not require that package.

### References:

- Solution here is adapted form [Array with Strings that are displayed on new line with indentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59334/4301).
- [What is the proper method of accessing a counter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21561/what-is-the-proper-method-of-accessing-a-counter)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forarray}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcounter{TotalNumberOfListMembers}%
\newcommand{\SetTotalNumberOfListMembers}[1]{%
    \setcounter{TotalNumberOfListMembers}{0}%
    \ForEach{,}{\stepcounter{TotalNumberOfListMembers}}{#1}%
}%

\newcommand*{\ProcessListMembers}[1]{%
\SetTotalNumberOfListMembers{#1}
\ForEach{,}{%
    \thislevelitem(\the\thislevelcount)%
    \IfEq{\the\thislevelcount}{\the\value{TotalNumberOfListMembers}}{}{: }% 
}{#1}%
}%

\begin{document}
    \ProcessListMembers{x,y,z}
\end{document}
```