# PGF's \foreach with weird list

Tags: pgf-core

A claim is made at [pgffor: Special treatment for last item in \foreach-list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16198/pgffor-special-treatment-for-last-item-in-foreach-list) that the following works. But I can't get it to work. What have I missed?

```
\newcount\nra
\foreach[count=\nx]\x in {1--,2--,...,10--}{%
  \advance\nra by1
  \ifnum\nra>2 \breakforeach\fi
  \texttt{\x (\the\nra)}\space
}
```

Also, please how do I get the following to work with `\foreach`?

```
\def\amspace{\let\amspace\space}
\newcount\nra
\foreach\x in {1pt,2pt,...,10pt}{%
  \advance\nra by1\relax
  \ifnum\nra>2 \breakforeach\fi
  \amspace\texttt{\x (\the\nra)}%
}
```

**EDIT** (2012/06/19)

**This is now a community question: everyone can edit it or provide his/her suggestions below**

I have reopened this question because I want to seek the opinion of users of `\foreach` on which of the following format is to be preferred for an ellipsis list, i.e., a list to be completed. Suggestions of other syntaxes are welcome.

`\foreach` currently supports the rather queer syntax, which is given on p.505 of the PGF-2.10 manual (just before the section titled *special handling of pairs*):

```
{0\pi,0.5\pi,...\pi,3\pi}
{A_1,..._1,H_1}
{1--, 4-- ,...--, 10--}
{1pt, 4pt, ...pt, 10pt}
```

**Proposals**

For incomplete (ellipsis) lists, the user should include optional key values after the loop list, as follows. This will significantly speed up list completion and reduce the possibility of mistaken identity.

Target list:

```
{a,B,1,5,A^1,A^3,A^5,A^7,A^9}
```

Syntax for \newforeach:

```
\newforeach [<conventional.keys>] \x in {a,B,1,5,...}[
  start = A^1,
  end = A^9,
  step = 2,
  coupler = ^,
  grow right, % increment right of <coupler>
  grow left, % increment left of <coupler>
  macro elements, % elements are macros
  ... more keys
]
{<loop.callback>}
```

`<conventional.keys>` will be the usual `\foreach` keys/variables with some few new ones.

Examples of when elements are macros:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\start{<expr>}
\pgfmathsetmacro\stopp{<expr>}
{\start,...,\stopp}
```

**Reminder**

`\newforeach` will work for arbitrary list separators and subseparators (including active list separators) and will remove the group scoping of computations by `\foreach`. New user variables will include

```
*parser = <value> (e.g., {,})
*subparser = <value> (e.g., /)
list is macro = <true> | <false> % the given list is a macro
terminator = <value> (e.g., {;}) % callback terminator
evaluate \x as \y using <formula>
count in \nr all \x satisfying <condition>
store in \cmd all \x satisfying <condition>
apply to all \x satisfying <condition> = <code>
apply to all \x in serial range [a,b] = <code>
at begin loop = <code>
at end loop = <code>
```

The star sign (`*`) on parsers will mean "remember and use this parser subsequently, until I change it".

A new boolean `\iflastitem` will be introduced, which can be toggled independently, on different nesting depths. Item counters (e.g., `\currentitemnumber`) will also be introduced on all nesting depths without collision between nesting depths. The loop can also look ahead for `\nextitem`. And in the case of premature termination of the loop with `\breaknewforeach`, or with a user-inserted list item (`\listbreaker`), the remainder of the list on the current nesting depth will be available in `\listremainder`. The `\newforeach` loop can also be paused with the user-inserted list item `\listpauser`.

Comment: According to the linked answer you need another `--` at the end of `...`: `{1--,2--,...--,10--}`.  But not sure that is the result you are looking for.  Same for the second case: `{1pt,2pt,...pt,10pt}` will make it compile.  Seems a bit "hackish" -- I know coming from me it sounds hypocritical. :-)

Comment: @PeterGrill: I think my syntax is the natural one and the loop should handle it like that, provided it was meant to handle such a list. The syntax you're suggesting seems to me to be a game of salamander; or is it poker?

Comment: I am not suggesting that that is good syntax, just that that is what the linked question shows, and does work.

Comment: I agree that the proposed syntax is more natural. Whoever developed `pgffor` hadn't the same idea, though. I can think of a reason why: how `\foreach\x in {11,...,91}` should be interpreted? If you try `{11,...1,91}` only nine cycles are performed.

Comment: Thanks to Peter and Percusse, or is it all lowercase (percusse)? I still can't find in the user manual where the syntax `{1--,2--,...--,10--}` is suggested. But I think a natural syntax is to be preferred. I propose a key/variable called `list unit`, which can be assigned, e.g., `pt` or `---`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One has always to remember that `\foreach` processes the token list to be repeated inside a group, so redefinitions and assignments must be global:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}

\def\amspace{\global\let\amspace\space}
\newcount\nra
*\foreach\x in {1pt,2pt,...pt,10pt}{%
  \global\advance\nra by1\relax
  \amspace\texttt{\x (\the\nra)}%
  \ifnum\nra>2 \breakforeach\fi
}*
\end{document}
```

This avoids redefining `\amspace` many times as in percusse's answer.

About the syntax: one can think to something like

```
\foreach\x in {11,...,31}{...}
```

and

```
\foreach\x in {11,...1,31}{...}
```

In the former case 21 cycles will be performed, in the latter only three.

Comment: Hmm I forgot to put it inside the `\ifnum` to avoid redefinitions but still this is much better.

Answer (score 3):

For the first version, though a little disappointing, you need, `pgfmath` module. But note that, if you remove the `[count=\nx]`, you can also remove the `pgfmath` dependency. Also the detail Peter commented on, that extra `--` is needed. The motivation behind that is, I guess, to strip off the non-increasing parts and then evaluate the initial, incremental and the final numbers from a given list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\newcount\nra
\foreach\x in {1--,2--,...--,10--}{%
  \global\nra\numexpr\the\nra+1 %or \global\advance\nra by1
  \texttt{\x (\the\nra)}\space
    \ifnum\nra>2 \breakforeach\fi
}
\end{document}
```

For the second version, similarly

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,pgfmath}
\def\amspace{}
\begin{document}
Some text\foreach\x[count=\xi]in{1pt,2pt,...pt,10pt}{%
         \amspace\texttt{\x(\xi)}%
         \gdef\amspace{\space}
         \ifnum\xi>2\unskip\breakforeach\fi
}continues.
\end{document}
```

`\breakforeach` command does not terminate the remaining code for that item but prevents the loop run again. Hence it might be a better idea to leave it as the last line in the `\foreach`. If I remember correctly there was a note about this in the manual.

I hope I got the space argument right otherwise please discard this.