# draw line between points given by single command

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, foreach

What I want to do is draw a line between points that are defined in a command like this but without the connect to (0,0):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\new{0.85,0.81,0.77,0.73,0.77}
\draw (0,0)
  \foreach \y [count = \xi ] in \new {-- (\xi,\y*10)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The points in \new are auto generated by another program, so I cannot hard code the first coordinate into the first point. Is there a way to solve this without splitting the list beforehand?

Comment: please provide complete small document with your deffinitins in its preamble needed for compilation of your code snippet.

Comment: but i ask you for complete document ... is so difficult to extend your code snippet to it?

Comment: @Zarko it should be a working example now

Comment: yes, now it is :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to include an `\if` clause (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16352/47927)):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.append style=fill]

\def\new{0.85,0.81,0.77,0.73,0.77}
\draw 
\foreach \y [count = \xi] in \new {
 \ifnum\xi>1--\fi (\xi,\y*10) node[dot](point\xi){}
};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]